# Send FormData through Ajax POST method return 403

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, p5.js

I write an application with speech recognition. All I want is to record some speech and send it to server where I will convert it into text. And I have a problem with sending that sound file. I record voice using p5.js library and when I try to download it there is no problem.

The problem is when I try to send it to server using ajax.

**script.js**

```
function toggleRecording(e) {
    if (e.classList.contains("recording")) {
        recorder.stop();    
        e.classList.remove("recording"); 
        sendAudioToServer(soundFile)
    } else {
        e.classList.add("recording");
        recorder.record(soundFile);
    }
}

function sendAudioToServer(soundFile)
{
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('fname', 'test.wav');
    data.append('data', soundFile);

    console.log(soundFile);
    console.log(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/recognizeCommand',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(data) {
          alert("works!");
        },    
        error: function() {
          alert("not works!");
        }
    })
```

**Java controller**

```
@PostMapping("/recognizeCommand")
public @ResponseBody String recognizeCommand(@RequestParam MultipartFile mpf) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = mpf.getBytes();
        SpeechRecognitionApplication.logger.info(bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "finish";
}
```

When I stop recording regardless to `toggleRecording` function it should stop recording and send it to server. And there is a problem with `sendAudioToServer` function. Here is the result from Chrome console:

[image]

[image]

I'm not sure but there is probably problem with FormData. As you can see when I printed it in console it's empty. Founded some similar questions here but there is no solution to solve my problem.

**EDIT:**

After add `dataType: 'jsonp'`

There is that error:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**
After adding csrf token:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add csrf tokens as this.

```
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

In header:

```
var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
```

Set headers.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/recognizeCommand',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            // here it is
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
    success: function(data) {
      alert("works!");
    },    
    error: function() {
      alert("not works!");
    }
})
```

Try adding debug point here.

```
 SpeechRecognitionApplication.logger.info(bytes);
```

Comment: Ok, it helps to avoid 403 error. But it still return "not works!"

Comment: In web browser nothing, just this alert from error function

Comment: I mean what is the status code? 500 or something? You can check it from the browser network tab. Or may be any logs from Spring?

Comment: There is no status. Just alert "not works!" from error function, no logs in console, no logs in spring, in network tab in Chrome there is also nothing

Comment: Please share them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173509/discussion-between-supun-dharmarathne-and-rafal-sokalski).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `dataType: 'jsonp'` to your `$.ajax` call like,

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/recognizeCommand',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("works!");
    },    
    error: function() {
      alert("not works!");
    }
})
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I made it, but there is another error. Look at edit please

Comment: @RafałSokalski Sorry, I missed a **,**  (comma) after that line, Can you please add that comma and check?

Comment: I did it with comma, Without it there was Unexpected identifier

Comment: It should be json or jsonp ?

Comment: For these 403 type errors, we may require to change json to jsonp

Comment: What happens when you make it as `json` instead of `jsonp`?

Comment: I found this line in Spring logs:        Written [{timestamp=Wed Jun 20 20:49:27 CEST 2018, status=403, error=Forbidden, message=Forbidden, path=/recognizeCommand}] as "application/json" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@44384b4a]

Comment: Have you enabled SpringSecurity in this project?

Comment: @SupunDharmarathne yes there is Spring Security. I was thinking that it might be a problem because I had many issue with this.