# Pass data from datepicker form to APIView

Tags: django, view, django-rest-framework, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm currently trying to load dynamically a graph on my website using graphjs. What I want to do is to update data by choosing a time range or a specific datatype. I want it to be more flexible and only have two views; one for rendering the graph and other to return pertinent data. 
I think my date widget will pass data through HomeView with a post method. How can I pass date information to GenericDataView ? Or maybe there is an other way to do this kind of thing.

**EDIT** :

```
class HomeView(View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        return render(request,'charts/charts.html')

class GenericDataView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        selected_data = getDataFromTimeRange()

        if selected_data is not None:
             return Response(selected_data)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = DatePickerCustom(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                mydate = form.cleaned_data('production_day')
                print("DATE: ", mydate)
        else:
            form = DatePickerCustom()

def getDataFromTimeRange():
     // do things
     return data;
```

In forms.py :

```
dateCustomInput = DateInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker'})

class DatePickerCustom(Form):
    production_day = DateField(label='Production day',widget=dateCustomInput)
```

And in charts.hmtl :

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            console.log(xhr)
            console.log(csrftoken)
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            console.log(X-CSRFToken)
        }
    }
});
<div class="chart-container"  url-endpoint='{% url "api-data" %}' style="position: relative">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<form action="chart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <!-- {{ csrf_input }}-->
    {% csrf_token %} 
    <label for="date">Choose a date: </label>
    <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="selectedDate" value="{{ form }}">
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

Comment: Use ajax to send a POST request to `chart` url (which will reach the `GenericDataView` view) with the date information

Comment: I've tried using POST request but I get a 403 error, I'm trying to fix this by passing credentials like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50954926/send-formdata-through-ajax-post-method-return-403)

Comment: When using AJAX, you need to send the value of the `csrftoken` cookie along with the request

Comment: Alright, do you know how can I do that correctly ?

Comment: To set the csrf token on ajax requests for Django you should set the `X-CSRFToken` header on your request.  There's some examples in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Comment: I've edited my question so you can see what I'm doing with csrf_token. I must be doing something wrong because it's still not working. I didn't wrote it down but there is also an ajax function for datepicker